# Unable to open chrome using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the following code to run chrome driver:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestClass 
{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/raisa/Documents/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/raisa/Documents/Selenium/chromedriver.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:11)
```

I have downloaded the latest chrome driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Which OS are you using ? If windows then you have to add the drive letter.

Comment: I am using Mac- OS X

Comment: So then why does your driver path end with `.exe` ?  does `/Users/raisa/Documents/Selenium/chromedriver.exe` exist ?

Comment: I added .exe being an executable file. So how should the path look like?

Comment: It should be something like `/Users/raisa/Documents/Selenium/chromedriver` without `.exe` on MacOS. also make sure that the `chromedriver` file is in the actual path. (try `ls /Users/raisa/Documents/Selenium/chromedriver` in terminal)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the comments.
On Mac OS you **will not** need `.exe` after `chromedriver`.

For your example you'll want it to look like this: `/Users/raisa/Documents/Selenium/chromedriver`.

I've also seen this problem come up because the execute permissions wasn't set for the file.
So double check the file permissions, and also that the file is in the actual path given.

Answer (score 0):

Through terminal navigate to the place where chromedriver is located and then execute following command.

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine chromedriver